# Highlighting an entire week in Datepicker JQuery UI (1.10.x) and JQuery (1.9.x)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, highlight

I am having the hardest time porting this jsFiddle: 
 http://jsfiddle.net/manishma/NCHtH/ 
to `JQuery 1.9.1` (with `JQuery UI 1.10.3`). 
 
 I tried the obvious, changing `live` to `on`, but that did not work. 
 
 I have spent way too much time and effort on this, and would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that, for reasons I cannot fathom, jQueryUI has changed when the datepicker is constructed. On your initial call to create the datepicker, jQueryUI only builds the following:

```
<div id="ui-datepicker-div" class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all ui-weekpicker"></div>
```

It doesn't build the rest of the datepicker control until it's shown for the first time. After  that the DOM structure for the control is added normally.

Because of this, `$('.ui-weekpicker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr')` has a length of `0` so the `mousemove` and `mouseleave` handlers are not attached.

The solution I came up with was to change the selector to delegate the events to `$('.ui-weekpicker')` (and change `.live()` to .`on()`):

```
$('.ui-weekpicker').on('mousemove', 'tr', function () {
    $(this).find('td a').addClass('ui-state-hover');
});
$('.ui-weekpicker').on('mouseleave', 'tr', function () {
    $(this).find('td a').removeClass('ui-state-hover');
});
```

Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NCHtH/19/